# How to get list of age from date and birthday for a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, date, arraylist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXu5p.png)

I have a dataframe with 2 column having list of 'birhday' and 'date'. How to create column having list 'age' from these columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use apply -

```
test = [
    ['8/17/2008', ['2005', '2004']],
    ['8/15/2008', ['2007', '2006']]
]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['date', 'year'])
dataframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date'])

def calculate_year(row):
    age = []
    for year in row['year']:
        age.append(row['date'].year - int(year))
    return age

dataframe['age'] = dataframe.apply(calculate_year, axis=1)
```

or

```
dataframe['age'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: [
    row['date'].year - int(year)
    for year in row['year']
], axis=1)
```

[image]